# bootstrap breadcrumb not showing two items per tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-lists, breadcrumbs

I'm having some issues bootstrap breadcrumb displayed in tabs. I want to both items side-by-side (similar to a tab in chrome). However, unable to do this properly. Any suggestions?

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="/zika">Zika Virus</a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ol>
```

[image]

EDIT:
To be more precise and clear, I want both items in the same tab. In my application, I will have tabs, each containing a topic and a close icon. I'm trying to create a UI similar to that of a internet browser tabs.

If this is not possible with this format, any suggestions in designing this UI would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took much longer than I expected, but it works. Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2byoq2um/7/)

How it works:

Bootstrap turns each child of `<li class="active">` into tabs. The reason you were getting 2 tabs is because *each* `<a>` was turning into a tab, even though they were in the same `<li>`.

The CSS I wrote overwrites this to turn the `<li class="active">` into the tab, rather than the children (by turning into a tab, I mean giving it borders, padding, etc.)

```css
.nav-tabs li {
  /* Give Bootstrap CSS normally applied to children
               to the tab container */
  color: #555 !important;
  cursor: default !important;
  background-color: #FFF !important;
  border: 1px solid #DDD !important;
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  margin-right: 2px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0 !important;
  position: relative !important;
  display: block !important;
  padding: 10px 15px !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  list-style: none !important;
}
.nav-tabs li * {
  /* Overwrite Bootstrap CSS */
  border: none !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  /* To display on the same line */
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Zika Virus</a>
      <a class="custom-inline" href="#"><i class="fa fa-close">   X</i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I want both items in the same tab, your approach creates two tabs. In my application, I will have multiple tabs, each containing a topic and a close icon.

Comment: I actually made a typo copying and paste certain parts of the code. I have edited the code in my code snippet now. I also added an EDIT section with further clarifications.

Comment: I have updated my answer, it basically uses CSS to overwrite Bootstrap code

Comment: That looks fantastic. I'll incorporate those changes into my code. Thanks for your answer

Comment: No problem! If this answered your question, please vote it up and mark it as accepted (click the tick underneath the voting buttons)